# Flutter : set state not update ui after re-open screen

Tags: flutter

when open the screen first time using GoRouter the ui updated normally .. but after go back and reopen the screen or close the screen and re-open it ..  the ui not updated

and also tryng to user statlesswidget with cubit and same error

```
class _VoiceCallState extends State<VoiceCallViewBody> {
  _VoiceCallState(this.model);

  .
  .
  .
  bool _isJoined = false; // Indicates if the local user has joined the channel
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   .
   .
   .
    setupVoiceSDKEngine(token);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    await agoraEngine.leaveChannel();
    stopRecord();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> setupVoiceSDKEngine(String token) async {
    // retrieve or request microphone permission
    await [Permission.microphone].request();

    //create an instance of the Agora engine
    agoraEngine = createAgoraRtcEngine();
    await agoraEngine.initialize(RtcEngineContext(appId: appId));

    // Register the event handler
    agoraEngine.registerEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        onJoinChannelSuccess: (RtcConnection connection, int elapsed) {
          setState(() {
            _isJoined = true;
          });
        },
         
         
      ),
    );
    agoraEngine.setEnableSpeakerphone(false);
    join(token);
  }
```

Comment: With having a quick look, I would say that it might be because you never set `_isJoined` back to `false`. You could do this in the `dispose()` function.